# Android ros Subscriber custom messages

Tags: android, ros

I am having problems when creating a new subscriber to a custom message in my android app. I have the same code in a java project and works ok showing the information message in the terminal.

The error log is:

```
E/UpdatePublisherRunnable(4793): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "arturo-desktop": No address associated with hostname
```

I create the subscriber this way:

```
Subscriber<meta_msgs.NodesList> subscriber2 = connectedNode.newSubscriber("nodes_list", meta_msgs.NodesList._TYPE);
    subscriber2.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<meta_msgs.NodesList>() {
        @Override
        public void onNewMessage(meta_msgs.NodesList message) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "OK. Message Received!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });
```

My custom message is composed of custom messages too. Here are the codes:

NodesList.msg:

```
Header header #for timestamp
NodeInfo[] nodes # an array of the nodes
```

NodeInfo.msg:

```
# This message holds info of a ROS node
# 

# Possible levels of operations
byte OK=1
byte ERROR=0

string node_name # the name of the node
byte status # status of the ros node regarding master connectivity
ROSTopic[] subs
ROSTopic[] pubs
ROSParameter[] params # the parameters of the node
string[] errors # latest history of relevant messages sent to rosout from the node
```

ROSParameter.msg:

```
string type # see OMTypes.msg for values
string name
uint8[] value
```

ROSTopic.msg:

```
string name # name of the topic
string type # type of the message
```

OMTypes.msg:

```
# Python format characters are used to simplify the Python code
string INTEGER=i    
string STRING=64p
string DOUBLE=d
```

Does anybody have problems when trying custom messages with Android?
Thanks! Its very important for me!

Comment: The error log I have is:
E/UpdatePublisherRunnable(4793): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "arturo-desktop": No address associated with hostname